# How to index aws snapshot output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

Here I am printing my snapshots.  I posted below what I would like the snapshot print out to look like, and would also like to be able to print individual snapshots.  I am not sure how to do this any help would be great.

```
svc := ec2.New(&aws.Config{Region: "us-east-1"})
params := &ec2.DescribeSnapshotsInput{
    OwnerIDs: []*string{
        aws.String("130300684064"),
    },
}

b, err2 := svc.DescribeSnapshots(params)
if err2 != nil {
    panic(err2)
}
fmt.Printf(awsutil.StringValue(b))
```

Here is what gets outputted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcRMB.jpg
This is what I would like to be output:

```
{

Snapshots:

----0

  Description: "Snapshot from MULTI",

  Encrypted: false,

  OwnerID: "130300684064",

  Progress: "100%!"(MISSING),

  SnapshotID: "snap-81b1dff6",

  StartTime: 2015-07-21 18:41:54 +0000 UTC,

  State: "completed",

  VolumeID: "vol-5121ebaa",

  VolumeSize: 1

},{

----1

  Description: "Snapshot from MULTI",

  Encrypted: false,

  OwnerID: "130300684064",

  Progress: "100%!"(MISSING),

  SnapshotID: "snap-08352a7f",

  StartTime: 2015-07-21 18:41:54 +0000 UTC,

  State: "completed",

  VolumeID: "vol-9b21eb60",

  VolumeSize: 1

},{

----2

  Description: "Snapshot from MULTI",

  Encrypted: false,

  OwnerID: "130300684064",

  Progress: "100%!"(MISSING),

  SnapshotID: "snap-768ffb00",

  StartTime: 2015-07-21 18:41:54 +0000 UTC,

  State: "completed",

  VolumeID: "vol-5620eaad",

  VolumeSize: 1

}]
```

Full code here: http://pastebin.com/QgmV6kRj

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to have the out puts indexed"? Do you want to sort the slice of ec2.Snapshot structs?

Comment: My volumes command give a nice output like this: http://imgur.com/ykUeCct , looking into ec2.Snapshotsstructs now.  I would like volumes to look the way snapshots looks.

Comment: I still don't know what you're looking for. Please ask a question, describing your problem, and what you would like to get as output: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My comment is too long i have to use pastebin: http://pastebin.com/gqGFtjHD        Thank you for helping me with this!

Comment: You don't need to put it in the comments, just update your question with all relevant information.

Comment: Just to be sure, all you're asking how to print the index number before you print each Snapshot struct?

Comment: Yes.  I really would love to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the details of the individual snapshots, you can iterate over the response:

```
resp, err := svc.DescribeSnapshots(params)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for i, s := range resp.Snapshots {
    fmt.Printf("Snapshot: %d\n", i)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: Perfect, THANKYOU.  This is exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @newtogolang: you know you're already doing this *exact* same thing elsewhere in your code? I would advise you go back and reevaluate your code, and learn *why* it does what it does (plus, there's a lot of questionable pieces in that code which could be cleaned up)